# What does Pratchett's "poets notwithstanding" joke mean?

Tags: discworld, terry-pratchett

In Terry Pratchett's *Equal Rites*, he writes the following passage:

> Esk, in fact, moved through the fair more like an arsonist moves through a hayfield or a neutron bounces through a reactor, poets notwithstanding, and a hypothetical watcher could have detected her random passage by tracing the outbreaks of hysteria and violence.

I don't understand the meaning of the phrase "poets notwithstanding" here. I've assumed it's a joke, but I'm struggling to understand the punchline. I vaguely recall *The Light Fantastic* having a running joke about the use of metaphors, but I don't quite see the connection here.

What is Pratchett trying to say with the phrase "poets notwithstanding" here?

Comment: @jo1storm, the trick is knowing what the poem is, and hence how you're supposed to move through a fair. When Pratchett makes such a joke it's always a direct reference to another work.

Comment: Thing insight that made this make sense to me, is that the "poets notwithstanding" is primarily tied to "her movement through the fair" nad not "neutrons bouncing through a reactor".

Comment: the scientifical truth is much better, you shouldn't let poets lie to you

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This refers to a previous remark by Pratchett in the text:

> According to the standard poetic instructions one should move through
> a fair like the white swan at evening moves o'er the bay

which in turn refers to the folk song *[She Moved Through the Fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_Moved_Through_the_Fair)*. So Esk moved through the fair "like an arsonist through a hayfield" etc, producing outbursts of violence and hysteria, in spite of the "standard" poetic instructions to move with tranquil elegance.

Comment: [She Moves Through The Fair](https://youtu.be/wM0vXXEvmh8), Sandy Denny.

Comment: or even "He Moves Through The Fair" - Sinead O'Connor.  It is more of a description of the meander through the fair (think pinball). The swan o'er the lake is more of the trip home. Swans in flight move at velocity in a straight line..